# How to default a SVG sprite if an ID was not found

Tags: html, svg, svg-sprite

I have a sprite of SVGs and a list of icons/logos in my database.

I loop through all of them and use a templating engine to generate my icons, such as:

```
<div class="partsvg__container">
  <svg class="partsvg__wt-icon partsvg__wt-icon--{{icon}}">
    <use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#wt-icon-{{icon}}"></use>
  </svg>
</div>
```

I might not have a SVG for every item in the database, and in that case the template renders an empty space.

How do I do so that if (for instance) `svg/icons.svg#wt-icon-stackoverflow` is not present in the spite, to still show a default one (ie: `svg/icons.svg#wt-icon-default`)?

Comment: Why not just have a default icon (`wt-icon-default`), and set the `icon` property to `"default"` for any records for which you don't have an icon?

Comment: I know, but there is no connection between the database clients and how many svgs the design team managed to implement.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution!
You can insert a symbol in your svg for the "not found case". In this way, if the symbol isn't found, a placeholder will be draw in the background.

```
<div class="partsvg__container">
  <svg class="partsvg__wt-icon partsvg__wt-icon--{{icon}}">
    <use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#wt-icon-{{'Placeholder'}}"></use>
    <use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#wt-icon-{{icon}}"></use>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: But if the icon is found, then both will appear.

Comment: @GRboss Yes, but the found icon will overlap the "placeholder" icon, so you will only see one icon